# moving the paragraph title to the next page

Tags: spacing, sectioning, paragraphs

I write document in Latex

`\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage, twoside]{article}`

And I created new command *myparagraph*, just to create new line (something like enter) effect (because \paragraph haven't done that.)

`\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}`

And now I have a new problem, because sometimes when I create new \myparagraph the paragraph title name stays one one page and the content is on the next one (beacuse it's to big to fit in the previous where the paragraph title is). What can I do to move the paragraph name to the next page, when content of this paragraph does that. I attach a photo which shows the problem.

[image]

Comment: If you don't want `\paragraph` to be a in-text header, but printed on a line on its own with standard class `article`, you should use a package like `titlesec` to reconfigure the style. Using `\mbox[}\\` is a ugly hack. Using `\mbox{}\\*` would also be a hack. There are also classes, that already provide interfaces for such changes.

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example? Normally the figure should float to the next page, but the text from after the figure should appear below your paragraph heading.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve placing the content of a paragraph on a new line below the title of that paragraph by adding these lines to your `preamble`:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\sffamily\itshape}{}{0pt}{}[\quad -- \newline]
```

See the manual of `titlesec` (chapter 3) for the explanation of the formatting codes. Or even better - take a look at the excellent explanation and examples on the tutorial page of Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Sections_and_chapters .